Google Sheets can you insert multiple cell values between text in a cell?
I am trying to insert cell values in my google sheets to a cell with text. the challenge im running into is the text I need uses a lot of quotations so it has been interfering with some functions to do this.
The text I need to keep is so you can copy and past it to a configuration file. That is why there is quotations in the text I need.
Here is the text:

(QuestEntries=((QuestID=0,CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Icon_PowerStonesQuest_Complete.Icon_PowerStonesQuest_Complete',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Icon_PowerStonesQuest_Uncomplete.Icon_PowerStonesQuest_Uncomplete',QuestName="Voyage of Power",QuestDescription="Journey across the ATLAS to hunt for the Power Stones, and then bring them to the Center Maw!",UnlockFeatNames=("Dance10"),QuestPointsOfInterest=((PointOfInterestID=0,PointOfInterestName="Power Stone 1",UnlockFeatNames=("Dance1"),WorldMapPosition=(X=0.270476,Y=0.608229),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon.Item_InfinityGem_Icon',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=1,PointOfInterestName="Power Stone 2",UnlockFeatNames=("Dance2"),WorldMapPosition=(X=0.109152,Y=0.889689),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon2.Item_InfinityGem_Icon2',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=2,PointOfInterestName="Power Stone 3",UnlockFeatNames=("Dance3"),WorldMapPosition=(X=0.593813,Y=0.254859),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon3.Item_InfinityGem_Icon3',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=3,PointOfInterestName="Power Stone 4",UnlockFeatNames=("Dance4"),WorldMapPosition=(X=0.419445,Y=0.074141),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon4.Item_InfinityGem_Icon4',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=4,PointOfInterestName="Power Stone 5",UnlockFeatNames=("Dance5"),WorldMapPosition=(X=0.390612,Y=0.398163),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon5.Item_InfinityGem_Icon5',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=5,PointOfInterestName="Power Stone 6",UnlockFeatNames=("Dance6"),WorldMapPosition=(X=0.410520,Y=0.908225),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon6.Item_InfinityGem_Icon6',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=6,PointOfInterestName="Power Stone 7",UnlockFeatNames=("Dance7"),WorldMapPosition=(X=0.733856,Y=0.259493),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon7.Item_InfinityGem_Icon7',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=7,PointOfInterestName="Power Stone 8",UnlockFeatNames=("Dance8"),WorldMapPosition=(X=0.904106,Y=0.576651),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon8.Item_InfinityGem_Icon8',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=8,PointOfInterestName="Power Stone 9 - Ghost Ship Route",UnlockFeatNames=("Dance9"),WorldMapPosition=(X=0.724932,Y=0.940490),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/HUD_GhostShip_Icon_Complete.HUD_GhostShip_Icon_Complete',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/HUD_GhostShip_Icon.HUD_GhostShip_Icon'),(PointOfInterestID=9,PointOfInterestName="Bring all 9 Power Stones to Center Maw",WorldMapPosition=(X=0.496857,Y=0.513336),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/HUD_BossLocation_Icon_Complete.HUD_BossLocation_Icon_Complete',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/HUD_BossLocation_Icon.HUD_BossLocation_Icon'))),

All of the X= and Y= values would be values pulled from the cells i calculated... here is a pic of what i have right now...
GoogleSheets Pic
I have tried to use this method...
=ArrayFormula("(QuestEntries=((QuestID=0,CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Icon_PowerStonesQuest_Complete.Icon_PowerStonesQuest_Complete',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Icon_PowerStonesQuest_Uncomplete.Icon_PowerStonesQuest_Uncomplete',QuestName=\"Voyage of Power\",QuestDescription=\"Journey across the ATLAS to hunt for the Power Stones, and then bring them to the Center Maw!\",UnlockFeatNames=(\"Dance10\"),QuestPointsOfInterest=((PointOfInterestID=0,PointOfInterestName=\"Power Stone 1\",UnlockFeatNames=(\"Dance1\"),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D6&",Y="&E6&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon.Item_InfinityGem_Icon',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=1,PointOfInterestName=\"Power Stone 2\",UnlockFeatNames=(\"Dance2\"),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D7&",Y="&E7&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon2.Item_InfinityGem_Icon2',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=2,PointOfInterestName=\"Power Stone 3\",UnlockFeatNames=(\"Dance3\"),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D8&",Y="&E8&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon3.Item_InfinityGem_Icon3',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=3,PointOfInterestName=\"Power Stone 4\",UnlockFeatNames=(\"Dance4\"),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D9&",Y="&E9&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon4.Item_InfinityGem_Icon4',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=4,PointOfInterestName=\"Power Stone 5\",UnlockFeatNames=(\"Dance5\"),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D10&",Y="&E10&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon5.Item_InfinityGem_Icon5',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=5,PointOfInterestName=\"Power Stone 6\",UnlockFeatNames=(\"Dance6\"),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D11&",Y="&E11&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon6.Item_InfinityGem_Icon6',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=6,PointOfInterestName=\"Power Stone 7\",UnlockFeatNames=(\"Dance7\"),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D12&",Y="&E12&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon7.Item_InfinityGem_Icon7',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=7,PointOfInterestName=\"Power Stone 8\",UnlockFeatNames=(\"Dance8\"),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D13&",Y="&E13&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon8.Item_InfinityGem_Icon8',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=8,PointOfInterestName=\"Power Stone 9 - Ghost Ship Route\",UnlockFeatNames=(\"Dance9\"),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D14&",Y="&E14&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/HUD_GhostShip_Icon_Complete.HUD_GhostShip_Icon_Complete',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/HUD_GhostShip_Icon.HUD_GhostShip_Icon'),(PointOfInterestID=9,PointOfInterestName=\"Bring all 9 Power Stones to Center Maw\",WorldMapPosition=(X="&D15&",Y="&E15&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/HUD_BossLocation_Icon_Complete.HUD_BossLocation_Icon_Complete',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/HUD_BossLocation_Icon.HUD_BossLocation_Icon'))),")


Escape the quotes " with another set of quotes "" as done below:
="(QuestEntries=((QuestID=0,CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Icon_PowerStonesQuest_Complete.Icon_PowerStonesQuest_Complete',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Icon_PowerStonesQuest_Uncomplete.Icon_PowerStonesQuest_Uncomplete',QuestName=""Voyage of Power"",QuestDescription=""Journey across the ATLAS to hunt for the Power Stones, and then bring them to the Center Maw!"",UnlockFeatNames=(""Dance10""),QuestPointsOfInterest=((PointOfInterestID=0,PointOfInterestName=""Power Stone 1"",UnlockFeatNames=(""Dance1""),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D6&",Y="&E6&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon.Item_InfinityGem_Icon',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=1,PointOfInterestName=""Power Stone 2"",UnlockFeatNames=(""Dance2""),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D7&",Y="&E7&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon2.Item_InfinityGem_Icon2',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=2,PointOfInterestName=""Power Stone 3"",UnlockFeatNames=(""Dance3""),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D8&",Y="&E8&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon3.Item_InfinityGem_Icon3',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=3,PointOfInterestName=""Power Stone 4"",UnlockFeatNames=(""Dance4""),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D9&",Y="&E9&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon4.Item_InfinityGem_Icon4',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=4,PointOfInterestName=""Power Stone 5"",UnlockFeatNames=(""Dance5""),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D10&",Y="&E10&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon5.Item_InfinityGem_Icon5',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=5,PointOfInterestName=""Power Stone 6"",UnlockFeatNames=(""Dance6""),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D11&",Y="&E11&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon6.Item_InfinityGem_Icon6',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=6,PointOfInterestName=""Power Stone 7"",UnlockFeatNames=(""Dance7""),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D12&",Y="&E12&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon7.Item_InfinityGem_Icon7',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=7,PointOfInterestName=""Power Stone 8"",UnlockFeatNames=(""Dance8""),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D13&",Y="&E13&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon8.Item_InfinityGem_Icon8',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/Item_InfinityGem_Icon10.Item_InfinityGem_Icon10'),(PointOfInterestID=8,PointOfInterestName=""Power Stone 9 - Ghost Ship Route"",UnlockFeatNames=(""Dance9""),WorldMapPosition=(X="&D14&",Y="&E14&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/HUD_GhostShip_Icon_Complete.HUD_GhostShip_Icon_Complete',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/HUD_GhostShip_Icon.HUD_GhostShip_Icon'),(PointOfInterestID=9,PointOfInterestName=""Bring all 9 Power Stones to Center Maw"",WorldMapPosition=(X="&D15&",Y="&E15&"),CompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/HUD_BossLocation_Icon_Complete.HUD_BossLocation_Icon_Complete',UncompletedIcon=Texture2D'/Game/Atlas/UI/Icons/HUD_BossLocation_Icon.HUD_BossLocation_Icon'))),"


okay, double quoting worked... I didnt copy yours as I need the "" in the text so I just double quoted the spots i needed to.
